# Copy constructor producing incorrect copy of old array

Tags: c++, arrays, copy-constructor

I have a class `vector210`, in which I am trying to create a copy constructor as is outlined below in the sample code below (only part of the complete code).

```
class vector210 {
    public:
    int arraySize;
    int values[1]; 

vector210(int array[], int arraySize_){
arraySize = arraySize_;
for(int i = 0;i !=arraySize_;i++){
    values[i] = array[i];
    }
}

vector210(const vector210 &p){
    int values [p.arraySize];

    for(int i=0;i<p.arraySize;i++){
    values[i] =  p.values[i];            
          };        
    arraySize = p.arraySize;

};


void print(){
for(int i =0;i <arraySize;i++){
    cout << values[i]  << endl;
    }

if (arraySize ==0){
    cout << "Vector is empty." << endl;
}
};
```

when I run the code in `main` as:

```
#include "CST210vector.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int v[5] = {1,2,3,4,5} ;
    vector210 test(v, sizeof(v)/sizeof(*v));

    cout << "Array to copy " << endl;
    test.print();
    cout << "Copied array values:"<< endl;
    vector210 testnew = test;
    testnew.print();
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << testnew.size() << endl; 
}
```

I receive the output to terminal:

```
Array to copy
1
2
3
4
5
Copied array values:
5
4198189
0
1
2
```

So somehow it seems like the array that is constructed when the copy constructor is called is wildly different from the array in the old version of the `vector210` object, but I am not sure how this is happening. Does anyone have insight as to how this error is coming about? I wish instead for my copy constructor to produce an exact copy of the original array.

Comment: Why `values[1]`? Is your vector supposed to hold only one element?

Comment: You have an array of 1 element. What possessed you to think you can assign an arbitrary amount of elements to it?

Comment: Just beginning to learn c++, is: int values[] better?

Comment: In your copy constructor, `int values [p.arraySize];` does not resize `values` member variable, it declared new local variable that shadows member variable.

Comment: The local variable values is shadowing the member variable with the same name.  As the other comments have already pointed out you need to dynamically allocate the array instead of using a array of size 1.

Comment: If you are just starting out, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of re-inventing it. If you are doing it as an exercise, and you haven't covered dynamic memory allocation yet, you aren't ready to implement it.

Comment: Yes, it is as an exercise.

Comment: If you are learning C++, get used to add `-Wall -Wextra` compiler flags. They will save you a few headaches. In this particular case, the compiler will warn you what @el.pescado and @gkamal explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong `vector210::values` should be a pointer and you should allocate memory for it. C++ doesn't have dynamic arrays. Your class and constructor should look like this

```
class vector210 {
public:
    int arraySize;
    int* values; // pointer!

    vector210(const int* array, int arraySize_) : 
            arraySize(arraySize_),
            values(new int[arraySize_]) { // allocate memory
        for (int i = 0; i != arraySize_; i++)
            values[i] = array[i];
    }
    ...
}
```

Now your copy constructor should be similar, it allocates memory using new.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an dinamic array. Compiler should complain about it

I will suggest use a pointer as int a [] become int * a, the following works fine to me

```
class vector210 {
    public:
    int arraySize;
    int *values;

vector210(const vector210 &p){
    values = new int[p.arraySize];
    memcpy ( values , p.values, p.arraySize*sizeof(int) );
    p.values[1] = 0;
    arraySize = p.arraySize;
}
```